# Errors coming up out of nowhere in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

First of all I want to say: yes, I know, Eclipse is bad, Android studio is 100 times better. But I'm working on a school project and I have a couple of days left after working on it for 5 months. That means that I'm not gonna switch to Android Studio now.

I worked with my builded app for 4 months straight now. I never experienced any problems, some errors but, they were all easily fixable. Now It's close to finished, and I find some strange errors. I changed none of my code, but suddenly I can't run it anymore. There are 100 lines of errors involving appcompat_v7, and I have no idea what they mean or how I can fix them. Here is an example of some error lines:

```
[2016-07-06 14:10:22 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2016-07-06 14:10:22 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-06 14:10:22 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2016-07-06 14:10:22 - Rodekruis]
```

Now I cleaned my project as someone told me that could work, and now all my "R"'s in my code are lined as errors. For example: R.id.button11, de R in this gives an error. This counts for every single activity that It's in. It tells me the following: 'R cannot be resolved to a variable'

Does anybody have a solution for this? I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Delete your R file and it will be auto generated again when you will build your project again.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) is same question. You can check other solutions too.

Comment: 'Just to make sure, I have an appcompat_v7 file, and my app file. My app file doesn't have an R.java file, my appcompat does. Should i delete it in appcompat_v7, then close eclipse, start it up again and run it?

Comment: @SurendraSingh It's not just the R.Java thing. I had those error lines in my question before I had the R errors. Those just added up when I cleaned my project.

Comment: try to change theme of your project. That error is any xml file error.

Comment: Could you also explain how I change the theme? Might sound stupid but I don't know where to find everything.

Comment: yes..!! you can delete R.java file appcompat_v7 file. It will be auto generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116582/discussion-between-surendra-singh-and-sneaky-and-stuff).

Comment: I did that, the errors are still there. I'm at work, and the chat link is blocked on my working network.